# How to convert byte array to unsigned 128 bit integer in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, md5, unsigned-integer

I am trying to hash strings using MD5. I need the hashed value as a 128 bit unsigned integer in Java.

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

String toHash = "HashThis";
md.update(toHash.getBytes());
byte[] isHashed = md.digest();
```

How do I convert isHashed to an integer?

Answer (score 1):

Use `BigInteger`.

`BigInteger value = new BigInteger(isHashed);`

To ensure that the resulting value is positive (as the byte array is expected to be in 2's complement), make sure the most significant bit is zero. This can be easily achieved by making the array 1 element bigger, with the first byte being 0.

Comment: Well, it assumes that the byte array is in two's complement, so you can just add a zero byte as the first one in the array to guarantee it.

Comment: It would be better to add the text of that comment into the answer, otherwise it's likely to get closed on the VLQ review queue....

Answer (score 1):

Java does not have a 128 bit int type. But it has a BigInteger class, which have a constructor that takes a signum and a magnitude expressed as a byte[], as you require.

```
BigInteger value=new BigInteger(1,isHashed);
```